# Assign column values from another dataframe with repeating key values

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, join, assign

Please help me in Pandas, i cant find good solution
Tried map, assign, merge, join, set_index.
Maybe just i am too tired :)

df:

```
   m_num  A  B
0      1  0  9
1      1  1  8
2      2  2  7
3      2  3  6
4      3  4  5
5      3  5  4
```

df1:

```
   m_num   C
0      2  99
1      2  88
```

df_final:

```
   m_num  A  B  C
0      1  0  9  NaN
1      1  1  8  NaN
2      2  2  7  99
3      2  3  6  88
4      3  4  5  NaN
5      3  5  4  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try**:

```
df2 = df[df['m_num'].isin(df1['m_num'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = pd.merge(df2,df1,on=[df1.index,'m_num']).drop('key_0',axis=1)
df2 = pd.merge(df,df2,on=['m_num','A','B'],how='left')
print(df2)
```

**Prints**:

```
   m_num  A  B     C
0      1  0  9   NaN
1      1  1  8   NaN
2      2  2  7  99.0
3      2  3  6  88.0
4      3  4  5   NaN
5      3  5  4   NaN
```

**Explanation**:

There may be better solutions out there but this was my thought process. The problem is slightly tricky in the sense that because 'm_num' is the only common key and it and it has repeating values.

So first I created a `dataframe` matching `df` and `df1` here so that I can use the `index` as another key for the subsequent merge.

```
df2 = df[df['m_num'].isin(df1['m_num'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

This prints:

```
   m_num  A  B
0      2  2  7
1      2  3  6
```

As you can see above, now we have the index 0 and 1 in addition to the `m_num` as key which we can use to match with df1.

```
df2 = pd.merge(df2,df1,on=[df1.index,'m_num']).drop('key_0',axis=1)
```

This prints:

```
   m_num  A  B   C
0      2  2  7  99
1      2  3  6  88
```

Then tie the above resultant `dataframe` to the original `df` and do a left join to get the output.

```
df2 = pd.merge(df,df2,on=['m_num','A','B'],how='left')
```

Comment: Do you think we could edit the title to something like 'Assign column values from another dataframe with repeating key values"?